# Stationary ball and Uncertainty principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Let us assume that a 1kg ball is placed on a table. If I can device a scale with least count $10^{-30}$ to measure both velocity and position simultaneously, it violates the uncertainty principle. What is the physical interpretation to 
rule out this possibility?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can imagine any scale you want, and devise an instrument with that scale ( bar smaller than Planck length). The constraint comes in measuring both at the same time momentum and position. The [Heisenberg uncertainty](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/uncer.html) (HUP) is an experimental fact, encapsulating the quantum mechanical behavior of the underlying framework of nature,

[image]

where $h_{\rm bar} = 1.054571800(13)×10^{−34} \rm joule\,second$

So the individual scales do not play a role except in concert, measurement of the properties at the same time. This is an experimental fact, all attempts obey the HUP.

What one calls "laws" in physics, or "principles", or "postulates" are axioms used in the theoretical models because they are continuously validated. Even one falsification would force a modification in the theoretical model, in this case quantum mechanics.

Comment: Thank you. My question was how can we physically rule out the possibility that both can be measured simultaneously in this case?

Comment: It is an experimental fact, that is all measurements done up to now simulatneously obey the HUP

Comment: this review has references for high precision tests http://www.currentscience.ac.in/Volumes/107/02/0203.pdf